# Windows 8.1 App C# XAML help: Save radio button selection when navigating back to previous page

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I'm trying to code an ESurvey application. I have a list of radio buttons in each page (A total of 7 pages), and I would like to make the radio buttons save its check state when the respondent clicks on the previous page.

```
using FYPPrototype1.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Popups;

// The Basic Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234237

namespace FYPPrototype1
{
/// <summary>
/// A basic page that provides characteristics common to most applications.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class SurveyPage2 : Page
{

    private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
    private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

    /// <summary>
    /// This can be changed to a strongly typed view model.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableDictionary DefaultViewModel
    {
        get { return this.defaultViewModel; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// NavigationHelper is used on each page to aid in navigation and 
    /// process lifetime management
    /// </summary>
    public NavigationHelper NavigationHelper
    {
        get { return this.navigationHelper; }
    }


    public SurveyPage2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Populates the page with content passed during navigation. Any saved state is also
    /// provided when recreating a page from a prior session.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">
    /// The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/>
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that provides both the navigation parameter passed to
    /// <see cref="Frame.Navigate(Type, Object)"/> when this page was initially requested and
    /// a dictionary of state preserved by this page during an earlier
    /// session. The state will be null the first time a page is visited.</param>
    private void navigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Preserves state associated with this page in case the application is suspended or the
    /// page is discarded from the navigation cache.  Values must conform to the serialization
    /// requirements of <see cref="SuspensionManager.SessionState"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the event; typically <see cref="NavigationHelper"/></param>
    /// <param name="e">Event data that provides an empty dictionary to be populated with
    /// serializable state.</param>
    private void navigationHelper_SaveState(object sender, SaveStateEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    #region NavigationHelper registration

    /// The methods provided in this section are simply used to allow
    /// NavigationHelper to respond to the page's navigation methods.
    /// 
    /// Page specific logic should be placed in event handlers for the  
    /// <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.LoadState"/>
    /// and <see cref="GridCS.Common.NavigationHelper.SaveState"/>.
    /// The navigation parameter is available in the LoadState method 
    /// in addition to page state preserved during an earlier session.

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        navigationHelper.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
    }

    #endregion

    private async void Button_S2_S3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (RadioaAgree.IsChecked != true && RadioaNeutral.IsChecked != true && RadioaDisagree.IsChecked != true)
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("One or more options not selected. Please complete all options before proceeding!");
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }

        else if (RadiobAgree.IsChecked != true && RadiobNeutral.IsChecked != true && RadiobDisagree.IsChecked != true)
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("One or more options not selected. Please complete all options before proceeding!");
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }

        else if (RadiocAgree.IsChecked != true && RadiocNeutral.IsChecked != true && RadiocDisagree.IsChecked != true)
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("One or more options not selected. Please complete all options before proceeding!");
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }
        else if (RadiodAgree.IsChecked != true && RadiodNeutral.IsChecked != true && RadiodDisagree.IsChecked != true)
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("One or more options not selected. Please complete all options before proceeding!");
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SurveyPage3));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Much appreciated to all the kind coders out there helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply store a local variable, like a boolean, and when returning to that page check for the variable value and change radioButtons state accordingly ;)

```
//  these is the namespace of your class
namespace FYPPrototype1
{
    // these is the region of your class, where all functions and variables are stored
    public sealed partial class SurveyPage2 : Page
    {
        //  these are local variables
        private NavigationHelper navigationHelper;
        private ObservableDictionary defaultViewModel = new ObservableDictionary();

        // this is your class constructor
        public SurveyPage2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
            this.navigationHelper.LoadState += navigationHelper_LoadState;
            this.navigationHelper.SaveState += navigationHelper_SaveState;
        }
.
.
.
    }
}
```

Now for achieve what you need, you have to do a more complex thing, as you can see you have a load and a save function, that is `navigationHelper_LoadState` and `navigationHelper_SaveState`, you can store and load there radioButtons's state ;)
For more understanding on how to manage these functions refer to these page, it explain it quite well ;): http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2014/05/23/windows-phone-8-1-frame-page-navigationhelper-suspensionmanager.aspx

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Can you elaborate a little more? Like how to store a local variable?

Comment: Do I put this in all of the pages that has radio buttons?

Comment: Thank you so much for providing the code. However, I'm getting this error:

`Error 1 Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct C:\Users\User\Desktop\FYPPrototype1\FYPPrototype1\FYPPrototype1\SurveyPage1.xaml.cs 23 13 FYPPrototype1`

I'm pasting this on SurveyPage1.xaml.cs

Comment: You simply pasted my code XD? if so it can't work it was an example for let you get how you store local variables

Comment: Yeah... XD I failed my C# so right now I have no idea what i'm doing.... But anyways I have a `private void backButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`. Is it possible to add in the code here or something to store the local variables?

Comment: Let me know if it worked ;), if you keep get that error post your code so i can find the error ;)

Comment: Local variables are local because you declare them like i showed you, if you create the same variable inside your function you will not be able to access it from other functions! Local variables insted can be accessed from all your class ;)
In the backButton function you can save the radioButton state ;) like this: if (yourRadioButton.IsChecked == true) this.booleanVariable = true;

Comment: I've posted my code above... where should the namespace be created?

Comment: Ok now i get if but first things first, you already have a namespace XD, i will change my code in the first answer to match yours so you can understand ti better ;)

Comment: Okay! Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Sorry to trouble you again, can you do an example for a textbox input too?

Comment: I've got the radio buttons and textbox working after adding this code `this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Enabled;`

The only problem now is that once the respondent has completed the survey, I need all the selections to be erased for the next respondent. Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: mmm, don't know sorry XD